# Issue with Inter-service authentication using JHipster 6.6 and Okta

Tags: jhipster, okta

Using JHiÀster 6.6 to build a microservices architecture application. I have a gateway and 2 microservices. All have been spun up using JDL with OAUTH2 authentication.

If I set the OAUTH2 provider as the internal KeyCloak server, all works well, I can log in at the gateway front end, and the requests to the microservices for various entities etc work.

When I switch over to OKTA, I get a refresh loop, which shows as a 401 Unauthorized in the network dev console in the browser each time. On the service / gateway side, I get no error logged.

I've got all groups assigned to the app in OKTA using the .* regex as recommended.

It feels like there is some issue / privilege with the non-user authentication but i'm not familiar enough with OKTA, and not seeing anything meaningful coming back from JHipster / Spring.

EDIT: Tweaked debugging, and the main point of failure in the microservice appears to be here:

```
2020-01-03 19:25:20.567 DEBUG 41074 --- [ XNIO-1 task-13] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/api/remote-sites'; against '/oauth2/authorization/{registrationId}'
2020-01-03 19:25:20.567 DEBUG 41074 --- [ XNIO-1 task-13] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/remote-sites at position 6 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter'
2020-01-03 19:25:20.568 DEBUG 41074 --- [ XNIO-1 task-13] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider
2020-01-03 19:25:20.612 DEBUG 41074 --- [ XNIO-1 task-13] .s.a.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher : No event was found for the exception org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException
2020-01-03 19:25:20.612 DEBUG 41074 --- [ XNIO-1 task-13] .o.s.r.w.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter : Authentication request for failed: org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Signed JWT rejected: Another algorithm expected, or no matching key(s) found
```

Comment: Are your groups in Okta named ROLE_USER and ROLE_ADMIN? If so, you might want to try it in an incognito window.

Comment: They are indeed - all the admin / user dependent roles seem to work in the GW and Service Registry. Also tried in incognito and no luck unfortunately.

Comment: Are you using your default authorization server? Your issuer should end in /oauth2/default? If you're using the org auth server, you can't validate your JWT.

Comment: Ahh - currently I can only hit https://(org).okta-emea.com/ or whatever it is. If I include /oauth2/default, it doesn’t work at all, and okta gives me a 404 on that page. Okta doesn’t give me any interface to add API endpoints / change them, however Okta day they have enabled oauth2 on the tenant (and the bare domain started working once this was enabled. Is there a part im missing?

Comment: Are you sure you have an Okta developer account? I'd try creating a new account at https://developer.okta.com/signup and using that account. It won't cost you anything to try it. You might be trying to use a Workforce account rather than a Developer account.

Comment: I’ve got a full paid up account of which I’m an admin

Comment: Does `https://{yourOktaDomain}/oauth2/default/.well-known/openid-configuration` resolve with a JSON response?

Comment: Made a dev account and that indeed worked - managed to get in touch with Okta and it appears the M2M oauth2 is an extra add on. Somewhat frustrating it’s not at all obvious from the dev package what is and isn’t included in the paid for! Thanks for your pointers - definitely got me on the right path! Working nicely on dev at least now.